# How to update my xcode if i download it from website?

Tags: xcode

I download my Xcode from: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and so I can't update it by the appStore , and I don't want download a whole new version. Is there anyway to update it just like use appStore?

Comment: Updating from the App Store is the same as downloading the whole new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to update it just like use appStore?

As rmaddy points out in a comment, updating from the App Store would download a whole new version of Xcode anyway. Your best bet is to install Xcode from the App Store, or download your preferred version from Apple's developer site and install that.